# In Swift what happens when two threads get and set a non-thread-safe property?

Tags: swift, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

Take this code for example:

```
struct MascotProvider {
    private static var _mascot: MascotType?
    static var mascot: MascotType {
        get {
            if _mascot == nil { _mascot = Mascot() }
            return _mascot!
        }
        set { _mascot = newValue }
    }
}
```

This code is not thread-safe because if `_mascot` is nil and two threads try to `get` `mascot`, two instances of `Mascot` will be instantiated. But which one will be returned?  Is it deterministic?

Further, what happens when thread X `get`s and then thread Y `set`s before X's `get` has finished initializing/returning? What exactly is happening in this case? What gets returned to X? I'm sure I've seen a `bad access` error occur in the past (I swear!), but can't reproduce it now.

Can someone provide a step by step breakdown of what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But which one will be returned? Is it deterministic?

Whichever one is assigned to `_mascot` last. It's indeterministic

Having a set occur during the middle of a get should fine. IIRC, assignment to pointers is atomic, so it's not like the `_mascot` will ever be in an inconsistent combination of an old and new value. It'll be either the full old value, or the full new value (and its indeterministic as to which it is).

Comment: "Whichever one is assigned to _mascot last" - So, if X gets there first, then Y right after, if X finishes initializing `Mascot` before Y does, X will wait to return until Y finishes initializing?. Similar question in the `set` case. If X starts `get`ting, and in the meantime Y `set`s. Will X return right after Y `set`s? Or will X wait until what it started initializing finishes. And would it return that, or what Y set?

Comment: @guptron It depends all depends on the order of threads. In my answer I actually made the mistake of assuming that this is a class being held by a pointer. In the case of a struct, then you can have consistency issues. E.g. thread X writes the first half, gets interrupted by thread Y which writes the whole things, then thread X resumes. The result will be that the first half would be that set by thread Y, and the last half will be that set by thread X

Comment: @guptron Basically the resulting bits are those that were last written to. If thread X wrote a bit last, that bit will be the value that thread X set it to. Same goes for Y. All kinds of combinations of results are possible depending on when exactly the threads are dispatched

Comment: Actually the struct scenario is more clear to me. The class scenario is still fuzzy as to which pointer would be returned to the caller based on my first comment.

Comment: @guptron From what I recall, assignment of pointers is an atomic operation on x86 CPUs, so there's no way of getting a "half baked" pointer the same way you can get half baked structs. Which ever thread happened to write last will have its value persist